# Dynamic set URLs in Java web app

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey

I have a Java rest based web project on which I want avoid showing weird URL for the end user. For example, currently I have the following for the login page:

www.mydomain.com/MyProject/pages/login.jsp

I want it to show for the end user as:

www.mydomain.com/login.jsp

How can I accomplish that effectively?

Comment: I think you can map the domain www.mydomain.com to MyProject/pages so that it displays only the end point jsp.

Comment: I have tried and it worked

Comment: can you accept the solution?